# Building a Ruby with RVM from a tarball

Tags: ruby, rvm

I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 with RVM.

```
[21:43:24] [william@enterprise ~]$ rvm install 1.9.3-p0
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/william/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p0 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
            Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 500
ERROR: The requested url does not exist: 'https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/src/ruby-1.9.3-p0.tar.bz2'
```

Looks like the RVM guys haven't gotten their hands on [1.9.3-p0](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/40527) yet. Is there a way to install with RVM from a tarball, or do I just have to be patient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type this to your terminal:

```
rvm get head
rvm reload
rvm install 1.9.3
```

[Source](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/10/31/ruby-1-9-3-p0-released/)